# Making a consistent API, what's less surprising?

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic

I have an API where there are property accessors like:

```
int foo()
```

Sometimes the properties can be "null". Since an int cannot be null, this is handled with a extra property to check null.

```
bool hasFoo()
```

What happens when people call foo() when it's null? Rather than have undefined behavior, the implementation of foo() internally checks hasFoo() and panics, which will typically kill the thread or process with an error message.

Things get more interesting with floats. Floats in this API have a null value: NaN. So for

```
float bar()
```

When hasBar() returns false, bar will always return NaN, which is quite well defined beahvior. In fact most types, strings, dates, etc have valid "null" representations. ints and bools are the odd ones out where 0 can be a valid value.

So my question is, should bar() also panic when hasBar() is false to be consistent with ints and bools? Or maybe it is ints and bools that should return 0 when they are null, and only by calling hasFoo() can you tell the difference between a real 0 and a null 0. What behavior is less surprising? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1: bar() also panic when hasBar() is false**

This will not be surprising behavior to me as if I am not assigning anything to a float, I shouldn't be expecting anything in return form it. Returning NaN is a convenient way to avoid exception in program and letting it finish what it is trying to doing, but if you are designing your own way to implement this, this would be less surprising. But this will bring in other issues as you will have to catch every exception that is thrown and handle in some graceful way.

**Case 2: only by calling hasFoo() can you tell the difference between a real 0 and a null 0**

This will surely be surprising as not everybody would be knowing that they need to check one other value to verify this is actual 0 or not,  but you will be handling exceptions gracefully in here.

Comment: One concern is this language doesn't have exceptions, so for case 1, we panic() which won't be easily "catchable" by the user. My library does catch it at the thread level and stop it from killing the whole program, but typically it's an error condition, and I'm leaning in support of that because calling bar() without checking hasBar() is a programmer error for integers, it can't ever be the right thing to do. For floats, you'd get NaN, for string "", etc. Which may or may not be ok, but I'd rather it also panics to be consistent across types.

Comment: The two different kinds of zeroes business is surprising on reflection, I don't like it. It will trip up more programmers than just always making it illegal.

Answer (score 1):

If an API would be returning nullable values, as a developer I would most prefer that the return types be nullable, if the language supports it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Along those lines, if you expect there to be a lot of nulls as a regular use case, then it might be better to create a wrapper response object that is returned, similar to this pseudocode example:

```
public class Response<T>()
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}
```

So, with this approach you would return Response < int > instead of int and Response < float > instead of float...etc.

Comment: It's more of less the same interface. You use foo().HasValue() and foo().Value() instead of just foo() and hasFoo(). Which is worse, both in terms of appearance and performance. It's orthogonal to the concerns in my question (what happens in your example when you call Response.Value if HasValue is false?)

Comment: The difference is that once I have the Response object, the API is no longer responsible for how the object is used. If I misuse the response object, it happens in my code. If the API throws an exception, I think the API developer didn't design it well.

Comment: Seems more like it's just making it someone else's problem. It doesn't really improve things as far as I can see.

Comment: The other advantage, is that this allows the caller to implement their own exceptions or null handling. Furthermore, this means the API does not have to provide methods such as hasFoo().

Comment: if `HasValue` is false you get an exception stating that you called `Value` when no value was available and you should check `HasValue` first before calling `Value`. you can't legislate for people using objects incorrectly

Comment: @SamHolder yes, that's the same as my int foo() behavior above. The question is should it panic or should it return 0. And for e.g. strings, should the getter panic or return empty string.

Comment: you should throw an exception IMHO, something like IllegalStateException (java) or InvalidOperationException (.net) to indicate to the developer that they are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: @SamHolder so I'm leaning in that direction too. But one caveat is that sometimes you don't care if your string is empty or not. It makes it easier to work with. So then the caller has to do `hasFoo() ?  foo() : ""`. That's at least explicit, but a little ugly, especially since I don't have a ternary operator. I could add a 3rd function fooDefault(x) which returns `hasFoo() ? foo() : x` but maybe that's getting carried away.

Comment: why do you need `hasFoo()` at all in that case? Just make that internal and make `foo()` return the value or the default...

Comment: to be honest I think @SilasReinagel suggestion to have a method which returns an object to handle this is the best solution, as the user cannot easily choose to get the value without knowing they should check `HasValue`. Having just those methods on the api it is not clear at all that there are methods to check first

Comment: @SamHolder the code is actually generated, and the foo() hasFoo() pattern is everywhere, it would be impossible for users to go very long without understanding it, so I don't think that's a concern. I can't do away with hasFoo() completely and use a foo(default) because it wouldn't be possible to distinguish the case where foo() is null vs foo() == default, which matters sometimes.